# how to get one row data value into two row data value using SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

could you help me

```
select emp_id Emp ID,start_time timing,last_time timing
from data 
where (emp_id=5500 and date_id='3/18/2014')
```

Actual Output is,

```
Emp ID  timing                       timing
5500    03/18/2014 18:30:08             03/18/2014 19:23:09
```

I need the following output

```
Emp ID    timing
5500    03/18/2014 18:30:08
5500    03/18/2014 19:23:09
```

how to get this output? please help me, i dont know how to get this data. thanks for advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could just `union` two selects:

```
select emp_id Emp ID, start_time timing
from data 
where (emp_id=5500 and date_id='3/18/2014')

union all

select emp_id Emp ID, last_time timing
from data 
where (emp_id=5500 and date_id='3/18/2014')
```

Comment: It will as long as you put the same criteria into `where`.

Comment: I mean, can't we pivot it instead ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this is with `unpivot`.  The following typically has about the same performance:

```
select emp_id as "Emp ID",
       (case when n.n = 1 then start_time
             else last_time
        end) as timing
from data cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
where emp_id = 5500 and date_id = '2014-03-18';
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have many rows then usng Union all or cross join will take time .. 
Alternately you can select two differeent query like

> select emp_id Emp ID, start_time timing from data  where (emp_id=5500
>   and date_id='3/18/2014')
>
> select emp_id Emp ID, last_time timing from data  where (emp_id=5500
>   and date_id='3/18/2014')

from code behind using generic list you can merge the both list object like

> List a = new List(); List b = new
>   List();
>
> a.AddRange(b);

Answer (score 0):

try to remove where clause. For multiple rows, it will work!

```
select emp_id Emp ID, start_time timing
from data 

union all

select emp_id Emp ID, last_time timing
from data
```